Suppress column already defined warning, tabularx, array
How can I suppress the column is already defined package warning caused by repeat uses of \newcolumntype with tabularx? (and therefor by extension the array package). I am intentionally redefining the using the same column letter.

Please provide some code that demonstrates the problem.  Then we don't need to guess, and we don't all have to go through the work of setting up the situation.

Normally warning are there for a reason... But one can always resort to the silence package. /me ducks

If you keep \newcolumntype segregated in an environment, you won't get warnings.
Anyway, here's a \renewcolumntype command that avoids the warnings, but issues a warning if you try to renew a nonexisting column type; the \newcolumntype action is performed anyway (just like \newcolumntype does normally).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\renewcolumntype}[1]{%
  \edef\NC@char{\string#1}%
  \@ifundefined{NC@find@\NC@char}%
    {\PackageWarning{array}{Column \NC@char\space is not defined}}%
    {\ExpandArgs{c}\let{NC@find@\NC@char}\relax}
  \newcolumntype{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{C}{c}

\begingroup
\newcolumntype{Q}{c}
\endgroup
\newcolumntype{Q}{r}

\renewcolumntype{C}{l}
\renewcolumntype{U}{c}

\begin{tabular}{CUQ}
aaaaaaa & bbbbbbbb & xxxxxxx\\
ccc     & ddd      & yyyy
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


The only warning is
Package array Warning: Column U is not defined on input line 24.

You can see that the \newcolumntype{Q}{c} inside the group is forgotten at group end and the subsequent \newcolumntype{Q}{r} doesn't raise warnings.

Can you help me translate this answer to expl3? I have multiple \cs_new_protected:Nn functions which each contain \newcolumntype. I intend them to function like you have shown, inside a group, where once they are done I no longer need the column types.

Nevermind, I found it on page 13 of interface3.pdf. \group_begin: and \group_end:. Thank you for the nudge in the right direction.

If you must, as for \newcommand, you can undefine the construct before making a new definition.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{u}{c}

\ExpandArgs{c}\let{NC@find@u}\relax
\newcolumntype{u}{c}
\begin{document}


\end{document}


Thank you for teaching me something new!
